# ggplot2- How to overlay group averages for trajectory plots of individuals separated by group using facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

Sorry if the question title is not worded right. Explaining here more clearly

As shown in the plots, I have data from participants in a study where

1. each subject was evaluated at the start and end of training (2 data points per subject)
2. Subjects belonged to 1 of 4 possible groups.

I was able to plot the trajectories for subjects in all 4 groups separately by getting the data in long format by melt (see screenshot of current dataframe) and then using facet_wrap.

Now I would like to show this but with the average lines for each of the 4 groups overlayed in there and distinctly separated from the individual subjects.

I am able to calculate the average (starting/ending values) for all 4 groups by using the "aggregate(df, group_column_name, mean)" function. But I am having a total brainfreeze on how to include them in these plots separated by facet_wrap and still have them highlighted to be distinctly different from the individual subject data points. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated

[image: current plot]
[image: dataframe used]

Answer (score 0):

If every line has a datapoint in all occupied x-position (0 & 30), you can just take the average by x-position and plot that. You can have the summary line stand out by setting the non-summary line with an alpha, or by increasing the size of the summary line.

```r
library(ggplot2)

# Dummy data
set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(
  name = rep(1:16, each = 2),
  days = rep(c(0, 30), 16),
  group = rep(LETTERS[c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4)], each = 2),
  value = rnorm(32)
)

ggplot(df, aes(days, value)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = as.factor(name), 
                group = name),
            alpha = 0.3, show.legend = FALSE) +
  stat_summary(geom = "line", fun = mean) +
  facet_wrap(~ group)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>